# What are the other use of Spring AOP except Logging and Exception handling?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Spring AOP and AspectJ are usually used for Exception handling and Logging. Is there any other feature for which we are using aspectJ and spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transactional behavior is the first to come to mind. Take a look at the `@Transactional` annotation. You mark a method with the annotation and the container will take the necessary steps to start a transaction before your method executes and commit or roll back the transaction when it ends.

Security is another nice application of AOP. You can annotate a method to mark it as requiring certain permissions. For example, in a web application, you might have a few handler methods for requests that require the user to be an administrator. Instead of implementing that logic in each handler method, you extract it to some AOP advice and put a joinpoint at each of those methods.

Aspects can be used as any type of filter really. You can allow, prevent, modify access to a method.

Note that Spring's support for AOP is limited to method invocation join points.